# Get records from two tables when one table has same values in a field in his foreign key

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables and I need to get only the records from Table A where the Table B in its field Status all the Status records are Process

```
Table A
---------------------------------------------------
Id        Folio        Date            Amount
YY1       001          01/01/2014       300
YY2       002          02/01/2014       400
YY3       003          03/01/2014       500
YY4       004          04/01/2014       600

Table B
---------------------------------------------------
Id        Table_A_Id        Status          
XY1       YY1               Process
XY2       YY1               Process
XY3       YY1               Process
XY4       YY2               Process
XY5       YY2               Rejected
XY6       YY2               Process 
XY7       YY3               Process
XY8       YY3               Rejected
XY9       YY3               Finish
XY10      YY4               Process
XY11      YY4               Process
XY12      YY4               Process
```

I want this

```
Id        Folio        Date        Amount
-------------------------------------------
YY1        001        01/01/2014     300
YY4        004        04/01/2014     600
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really try it out yourself, but take a look at this.

```
CREATE TABLE #table1(Id  VARCHAR(5), Folio VARCHAR(5), Date  datetime, Amount numeric(28,12))

INSERT INTO #table1(id, folio, date, amount)
VALUES('YY1', '001', '01/01/2014', 300)
INSERT INTO #table1(id, folio, date, amount)
VALUES('YY2', '002', '02/01/2014', 400)
INSERT INTO #table1(id, folio, date, amount)
VALUES('YY3', '003', '03/01/2014', 500)
INSERT INTO #table1(id, folio, date, amount)
VALUES('YY4', '004', '04/01/2014', 600)

CREATE TABLE #table2(id VARCHAR(5), table_a_id VARCHAR(5), status VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY1', 'YY1', 'Process')
INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY2', 'YY1', 'Process')
INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY3', 'YY1', 'Process')
INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY4', 'YY2', 'Process')
INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY5', 'YY2', 'Rejected')
INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY6', 'YY2', 'Process')
INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY7', 'YY3', 'Process')
INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY8', 'YY3', 'Rejected')
INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY9', 'YY3', 'Finish')
INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY10', 'YY4', 'Process')
INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY11', 'YY4', 'Process')
INSERT INTO #table2(id,table_a_id,status)
VALUES('XY12', 'YY4', 'Process')

SELECT *
FROM #table1 t1
WHERE t1.id NOT IN  (
                        SELECT table_a_id
                        FROM #table2
                        WHERE status <> 'Process'
                    ) 


DROP TABLE #table1
DROP TABLE #table2
```

Comment: No problem. If that answers your question, please accept answer.